# Can I automate creation of Google Cloud projects?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a use case where I need to create projects in Google Cloud for my clients.

The most expensive part of the app can be externalized to a project that will be charged directly to our clients (they will enter the billing info themselves, it's their data stored in their project).

Our **«main»** project will have access to all those projects and our customers will pay us only a monthly subscription.

1. Can projects be created through API?
2. How can this be automated?

Comment: You could create separate [billing accounts](https://support.google.com/cloudbilling/answer/6110821?hl=en&ref_topic=2991962) for each customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You have to agree to terms and conditions to create a project and this will not be automated.

A much better approach is to [use namespaces to implement multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy).

Comment: The OP wants to be able to have the costs split by customer. As far as I know multitenancy does not help you with this, and it certainly wont't help for Cloud Storage.

Comment: True, but even though the answer does not solve your requirements, it is still the correct answer: you cannot automate project creation.